# Populate my text box based on the my dataset using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, data-access-layer, 3-tier

I would like to populate my text box based on the my dataset.

**DAL**

```
public static DataTable GetCustomer(collection b)
{
    {
        DataTable table;
        try
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            DB = Connect();
            DBCommand = connection.Procedure("getCustomer");
            DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@CustomerRef", DbType.String, b.CustomerRef1);

            DbDataReader reader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            return table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }

    }

}
```

**BLL**

```
   public DataSet returnCustomer(collection b)
   {
       try
       {
           SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
           DataSet table = new DataSet();

           adapt.Fill(table, "table");
           return table;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

**PL**

```
protected void ddl_Customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DAL.collection cobj = new collection();
    BLL.business bobj = new business();

    string selectedValue = ddl_Customers.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //populate the text boxes
    txtCustomerRef.Text = bobj.returnCustomer(cobj);
}
```

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'string'

When i populate my text box I need to get the specific value from the dataset and that should be the customer ref. But I cannot see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `returnCustomer` returns `DataSet` but you try to assign it's return value to `txtCustomerRef.Text` which is a `string` and there is no implicit conversation between these two types. Consider to change your logic.

Comment: @SonerGönül: please can you suggest the change in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set `dataset` to text property of `textbox` as it accepts only string.

Assuming, 1st row and 1st column of 1st table of dataset has required value, change would be like following.

`txtCustomerRef.Text = bobj.returnCustomer(cobj).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();`

Also you need to add `null` check before doing `ToString`.

Comment: i get an error when selected a value from the drop down: `The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.`

Comment: That seems to incorrect for me, it just returns empty dataset, you need to fix that up and use my code.

Comment: I added, `adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;` but unsure how to define the sql command, because i am using DAL and though the SQL command needs a param and thats in the DAL...

Comment: I guess, original question is getting deviated from its actual error scenario, you need to ask DAL designer guy, who created that.

Comment: ill accept your answer as its correct, just thought you could help with 2 things

Comment: @PriceCheaperton, sure can you post your issue in separate question as this has already some other helpful things in it.